# Stream uploading large files using aws-sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to stream upload large files to S3 using aws-sdk?

I can't seem to figure it out but I'm assuming there's a way.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

### Update

My memory failed me and I didn't read the quote mentioned in my initial answer correctly (see below), as revealed by the API documentation for [(S3Object, ObjectVersion) write(data, options = {})](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#write-instance_method) :

> Writes data to the object in S3. This method will attempt to
>   intelligently choose between uploading in one request and using
>   #multipart_upload.
>
> [...] You can pass **:data or :file** as the first argument or as options. *[emphasis mine]*

The data parameter is the one to be used for streaming, apparently:

> `:data (Object)` — The data to upload. Valid values include:
>
> [...] **Any object responding to read and eof?**; the object must support the following access methods:
>
> ```
> read                     # all at once
> read(length) until eof?  # in chunks
> ```
>
> If you specify data this way, **you must also include the
>   :content_length option**.
>
> [...]
>
> `:content_length (Integer)` — If provided, this option must match the
>   total number of bytes written to S3 during the operation. **This option
>   is required if :data is an IO-like object without a size method**.
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

The resulting sample fragment might look like so accordingly:

```
# Upload a file.
key = File.basename(file_name)
s3.buckets[bucket_name].objects[key].write(:data => File.open(file_name), 
    :content_length => File.size(file_name))
puts "Uploading file #{file_name} to bucket #{bucket_name}."
```

Please note that I still haven't actually tested this, so beware ;)

---

### Initial Answer

This is explained in [Upload an Object Using the AWS SDK for Ruby](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html):

> **Uploading Objects**
>
> 1. Create an instance of the AWS::S3 class by providing your AWS credentials.
> 2. Use the AWS::S3::S3Object#write method which takes a data parameter and options hash which allow you to upload data from a file, **or a stream**. *[emphasis mine]*

The page contains a complete example as well, which uses a file rather than a stream though, the relevant fragment:

```
# Upload a file.
key = File.basename(file_name)
s3.buckets[bucket_name].objects[key].write(:file => file_name)
puts "Uploading file #{file_name} to bucket #{bucket_name}."
```

That should be easy to adjust to use a stream instead (if I recall correctly you might just need to replace the `file_name` parameter with `open(file_name)` - make sure to verify this though), e.g.:

```
# Upload a file.
key = File.basename(file_name)
s3.buckets[bucket_name].objects[key].write(:file => open(file_name))
puts "Uploading file #{file_name} to bucket #{bucket_name}."
```

Comment: That fails after a few minutes with "string contains null byte"  https://gist.github.com/1990541

Comment: @99miles: My memory failed me indeed, I've updated my answer regarding the erroneous interpretation of the AWS sample accordingly - please note that I still haven't actually tested this, so beware ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how big the files you want to upload are, but for large files a 'pre-signed post' allows the user operating the browser to bypass your server and upload directly to S3. That may be what you need - to free up your server during an upload.